# Inline CSS for blog post - table on mobile too large

Tags: html, css

*(Please note I have only some pretty basic self-taught knowledge of CSS and HTML, bootstrap is quite a new area for me. I'm working with inline CSS for this, since our IT person is the only one who can access the CSS style sheet. I don't wanna mess with that, to not mess the whole website up. I'm only responsible for the blogpost, so please no comment concerning this.)*

I am working on a blog post and designed a table for this, which shows different criteria that need to be fulfilled. Sadly on mobile it seems to be too large, but I'm not sure how to make it work for mobile. Here's the code for the first three rows:

```
<details style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: 500; padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px; background-color: white; border: 1px solid black;">
            <summary>Tabelle zur Hotelklassifizierung durch hotelstars.eu im textilen Bereich - für volle Ansicht klicken!</summary><br /><br /> <span>Leeres Feld = freiwillig, <i class="fa fa-dot-circle" style="color: #006666;"></i> = Mindestanforderung</span><br /><br />
            <table class="blogtable" style="max-width:95%;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 50%;">Kriterium</th>
                        <th>Punkte</th>
                        <th><i class="fa fa-star"></i></th>
                        <th><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i></th>
                        <th><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i></th>
                        <th><i class="fa fa-star"></i><br /><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i></th>
                        <th><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><br /><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Täglicher Handtuchwechsel auf Wunsch</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td><i class="fa fa-dot-circle"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="fa fa-dot-circle"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="fa fa-dot-circle"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="fa fa-dot-circle"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="fa fa-dot-circle"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Bettwäschewechsel mind. einmal pro Woche</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td><i class="fa fa-dot-circle"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="fa fa-dot-circle"></i></td>
                        <td><i class="fa fa-dot-circle"></i></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
</tbody>
            </table>
</details>
```

Can you help ?

Here are some images to see how it looks on desktop (how I want it to look like) and on mobile (broken)

[image: Screenshot of table]

Comment: If you want to retain the same layout one option is to add a horizontal scroll to the table on the mobile breakpoint.

Comment: Thank you! I'd also be willing to change the layout if there's a better solution.